# Reading Subdirectories with win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to read some sub-directories with win32 functions and it looks like this. Most everything works fine. I haven't got to run the function completely because I'm still debugging it. My problem: I have 5 actual files and two sub-directories. When I try to grab the file names of each subdirectory and file in the directory I get this: ".", "..", "Subdirectory1", "Subdirectory", "rest of the files"... Why did I get a period, two periods, and then the actual files in the folder?

```
static std::vector<std::string> ReadAllFilesIntoArray(std::string contentDirPath, std::string fileType)
{
    std::vector<std::string> filePaths;
    std::wstring strTemp;
    strTemp.assign(contentDirPath.begin(), contentDirPath.end());
    HANDLE hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    hFile = FindFirstFile(strTemp.c_str(), &FindFileData);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hFile)
    {
        int i = 0;
        do{
            // If it's a directory
            if (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY & FindFileData.dwFileAttributes)
            {
                // Convert wchar[260] -> std::string
                char ch[260];
                char DefChar = ' ';
                WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, FindFileData.cFileName, -1, ch, 260, &DefChar, NULL);
                std::string ss(ch);

                std::vector<std::string> localFilePaths = ReadAllFilesIntoArray(contentDirPath.assign(contentDirPath.begin(), contentDirPath.end() - 5) + ss + "//*", fileType);
                // Append the file paths found in the subdirectory to the ones found in the current directory
                filePaths.insert(filePaths.begin(), localFilePaths.begin(), localFilePaths.end());
            }

            // Convert wchar[260] -> std::string
            char ch[260];
            char DefChar = ' ';
            WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, FindFileData.cFileName, -1, ch, 260, &DefChar, NULL);
            std::string tempString(ch);

            // Then add to list if it's equal to the file type we are checking for
            if (tempString.substr(tempString.size() - 3, tempString.size()) == fileType)
            {
                filePaths.resize(i + 1);
                filePaths[i] = ch;
                i++;
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFile, &FindFileData));

        FindClose(hFile);
    }

    return filePaths;
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting to ANSI? Why not use wstring throughout? Or UTF-8 if you must use 8 bit text.

Comment: I make that mistake occasionally too, but I'm also learning the correct functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are special names that represent the current directory (`.`) and the parent directory (`..`). Enumeration code is typically written with special case checks to ignore these two special values.